# What features does scalacheck add over quickcheck?

Tags: quickcheck, scalacheck

All the scalacheck stuff says:

> has since evolved and been extended with features not found in Haskell QuickCheck

So, what are those features?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's the support for stateful testing (state machine testing). This functionality exists in the commercial QuickCheck offerings, but not in the free Haskell QuickCheck. ScalaCheck's API is also a bit richer than QuickCheck's API.

Comment: Has this changed after 3 years?